# EF Core: Why is one end of my nullable one-to-one relationship always null?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have a `Device` model, and a `Tid` model. Devices and TIDs can exist independently of each other, or can be associated together. If associated, then exactly one device can be associated with exactly one TID.

For this I need a nullable one-to-one relationship, meaning that either both ends are null, or both ends are not null.

I modelled this as follows...

```cs
public class Device {
  // Irrelevant properties excluded for clarity
  public string? TidId { get; set; }
  public virtual Tid? Tid { get; set; }
}

public class Tid {
  // Irrelevant properties excluded for clarity
  public string? DeviceId { get; set; }
  public virtual Device? Device { get; set; }
}

public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User> {
  // Irrelevant code excluded for clarity
  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder) {
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<Device>()
      .HasOne<Tid>()
      .WithOne(t => t.Device)
      .HasForeignKey<Tid>(t => t.DeviceId)
      .IsRequired(false);

    builder.Entity<Tid>()
      .HasOne<Device>()
      .WithOne(d => d.Tid)
      .HasForeignKey<Device>(d => d.TidId)
      .IsRequired(false);
}
```

However, when I set the `Tid` on a `Device` and save, although the navigation property is set on the `Device`, the navigation property on the `Tid` is not set, meaning that I can't see what device is associated with the device.

Same goes the other way round, if I set the `Device` for a `Tid`, then the navigation property is set on the `Tid` correctly, but the one on the `Device` is not, so I can't see what TID is associated with the device.

Looking in the database, it looks like it created two foreign key links between the tables, and I guess only one of them is being set, depending on which entity I update...

[image]

Can anyone explain how I should have done this. Thanks.

Comment: Use SQL Server Management Studio and check log file in the explorer under Management.  You should see a login when you run the c# code.  Verify the group and user are correct.

Comment: Primary keys have two purposes 1) To speed up linking two tables together 2) To create a one-to-one relationship.  You do not need a primary key if you do not have a one-to-one relationship.  One-to-one means ALWAYS.  If you do not ALWAYS have a relationship than remove the primary key.

Comment: You always need a one side!

Comment: @jdweng Not sure what you mean by your first comment. What does this have to do with users and groups? As for your second comment, I'm not sure what primary keys have to do with the question either. Just because the relationship is nullable does not mean I shouldn't have a primary key. Forgive me if I misunderstood, but I really don't understand either of your comments.

Comment: If you do not have permission to read the table you could get null results.  You picture of the database is showing to keys linking the Devices and Tids tables.  Why?

Comment: @jdweng I have full permissions on all tables. I link to the two tables because I need to associate them together as I explained in my question. How else would I associate them?

Comment: You have two primary keys and must use both or remove one of the keys.  You can't have your cake and pie too.  Keys help speed up the database and are not required. You have optional requirements and having two keys are going to give errors if you only use one key.  Only use keys when you have one-to-one for every case.

Comment: Did you get an answer to this? I have a similar problem and haven't been able to fix it